# how to fetch image from RSS feed

Tags: android, xml-parsing, rss, android-custom-view, feed

I am trying to fetch RSS news from a URL http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/1945062111.cms 
But I have a problem in displaying the images from this URL. Only the Title and the date are displaying but not the image.

[In this image description have some tags, I don't to show them. Only content should display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMgcN.png)

My second question is how can I edit the description fetched from RSS because it is displaying some  and  tag. I don't want to show them in my news. Only the data should be displayed.

Please show me where I should edit in this code.

```
package com.tandon.mynewsapp.fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.NetworkError;
import com.android.volley.NoConnectionError;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.ServerError;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.tandon.mynewsapp.R;
import com.tandon.mynewsapp.activity.DetailNewsActivity;
import com.tandon.mynewsapp.activity.MainActivity;
import com.tandon.mynewsapp.adapters.NewsListAdapters;
import com.tandon.mynewsapp.app.AppController;
import com.tandon.mynewsapp.models.News;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class LatestFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<News> newsdata = new ArrayList<News>();
    private NewsListAdapters newsAdapter;

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private boolean IsLoading=false;
    //private int totalPages=1;
    //private int currentPage =1;

    private String[] newsUrl;

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

    }

    private enum RSSXMLTag {
        TITLE, DATE, LINK, CONTENT, GUID, IGNORETAG,DESCRIPTION,IMAGE;
    }

    public LatestFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        newsUrl=this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.en_latest);

        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newsList);
        newsAdapter = new NewsListAdapters(getActivity(),newsdata);
        listView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                News news = newsdata.get(i);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailNewsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title",news.title);
                intent.putExtra("description",news.description);
                intent.putExtra("image",news.image);
                intent.putExtra("date",news.postDate);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        for(int i=0;i<newsUrl.length;i++)
        {
            getNewsPosts(false,newsUrl[i]);
        }


        swipeRefreshLayout=(SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipereferesh);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        newsdata.clear();
                        for(int i=0;i<newsUrl.length;i++)
                        {
                            getNewsPosts(false,newsUrl[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN);


//        News news1 = new News();
//        news1.setTitle("Title 1");
//        news1.setDescription("This is Description of news title 1 to check in program");
//        newsdata.add(news1);
//
//        News news2 = new News();
//        news2.setTitle("Title 2");
//        news2.setDescription("Description 2 for title 2 goes here");
//        newsdata.add(news2);
        //getNewsPosts();



        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    public void getNewsPosts(final boolean isRefresh,String url)
    {
        if(!isRefresh) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showPDialog();
        }

       // String url = "http://www.oneindia.com/rss/news-india-fb.xml";
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("News_World",response);
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).hidePDialog();
                //newsdata.clear();
                RSSXMLTag currentTag = null;

                IsLoading = false;
                if(isRefresh)
                {
                    //newsdata.clear();
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    //currentPage = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).hidePDialog();
                }
                try{
                    // parse xml after getting the data
                    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory
                            .newInstance();
                    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

                    //Abhishek Tandon Here
                    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                    if (currentapiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                        xpp.setInput(stream, null);
                    }
                    else{
                        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                        xpp.setInput(stream, null);
                    }

                    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
                    News newsItem = null;
                    //SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, DD MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {

                        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                            if (xpp.getName().equals("item")) {
                                newsItem = new News();
                                currentTag = RSSXMLTag.IGNORETAG;
                            } else if (xpp.getName().equals("title")) {
                                currentTag = RSSXMLTag.TITLE;
                            } else if (xpp.getName().equals("link")) {
                                currentTag = RSSXMLTag.LINK;
                            } else if (xpp.getName().equals("pubDate")) {
                                currentTag = RSSXMLTag.DATE;
                            }
                            else if(xpp.getName().equals("enclosure")||xpp.getName().equals("img")){
                                currentTag = RSSXMLTag.IMAGE;
                                newsItem.image=xpp.getAttributeValue(0);
                            }
                            else if(xpp.getName().equals("description")){
                                currentTag = RSSXMLTag.DESCRIPTION;
                            }
                        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                            if (xpp.getName().equals("item")) {
                                // format the data here, otherwise format data in
                                // Adapter
                                //  Date postDate = dateFormat.parse(newsItem.postDate);
                                //  pdData.postDate = dateFormat.format(postDate);
                                newsdata.add(newsItem);
                            } else {
                                currentTag = RSSXMLTag.IGNORETAG;
                            }
                        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                            String content = xpp.getText();
                            content = content.trim();
                            Log.d("NEWS_WORLD","Content ="+ content);
                            //Log.d("NEWS_WORLD","date ="+ newsItem.postDate);
                            if (newsItem != null) {
                                switch (currentTag) {
                                    case TITLE:
                                        if (content.length() != 0) {
                                            if (newsItem.getTitle() != null) {
                                                newsItem.title += content;
                                            } else {
                                                newsItem.title = content;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case DESCRIPTION:
                                        if (content.length() != 0) {
                                            if (newsItem.description != null) {
                                                newsItem.description += content;
                                            } else {
                                                newsItem.description = content;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case LINK:
                                        if (content.length() != 0) {
                                            if (newsItem.linkUrl != null) {
                                                newsItem.linkUrl += content;
                                            } else {
                                                newsItem.linkUrl = content;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case DATE:
                                        if (content.length() != 0) {
                                            if (newsItem.postDate != null) {
                                                newsItem.postDate += content;
                                            } else {
                                                newsItem.postDate = content;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        eventType = xpp.next();
                    }
                    Log.v("tst", String.valueOf((newsdata.size())));
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).hidePDialog();

                IsLoading = false;
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Request Time out error. Your internet connection is too slow to work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Connection Server error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Network connection error! Check your internet Setting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if (error instanceof ParseError){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Parsing error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);

    }

}

    /*
    public void getNewsPosts()
    {
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).showPDialog();
        String url = "http://rss.jagran.com/local/uttarakhand/almora.xml";
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("News_World",response);
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).hidePDialog();
                newsdata.clear();
                RSSXMLTag currentTag = null;
                try{
                // parse xml after getting the data
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory
                        .newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
                InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                xpp.setInput(stream, null);

                int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
                News newsItem = null;
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "EEE, DD MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {

                    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        if (xpp.getName().equals("item")) {
                            newsItem = new News();
                            currentTag = RSSXMLTag.IGNORETAG;
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equals("title")) {
                            currentTag = RSSXMLTag.TITLE;
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equals("link")) {
                            currentTag = RSSXMLTag.LINK;
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equals("pubDate")) {
                            currentTag = RSSXMLTag.DATE;
                        }
                        else if(xpp.getName().equals("img")){
                            currentTag = RSSXMLTag.IMAGE;
                        }
                        else if(xpp.getName().equals("description")){
                            currentTag = RSSXMLTag.DESCRIPTION;
                        }
                    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                        if (xpp.getName().equals("item")) {
                            // format the data here, otherwise format data in
                            // Adapter
                          //  Date postDate = dateFormat.parse(newsItem.postDate);
                          //  pdData.postDate = dateFormat.format(postDate);

                            int start = newsItem.description.indexOf("http");
                            int end = newsItem.description.indexOf(">");
                            String img = newsItem.description.substring(start, end);
                            Log.d("Image", img);
                            newsItem.image=img;

                            end = newsItem.description.indexOf(">");
                            newsItem.description= newsItem.description.substring(end + 1);

                            newsdata.add(newsItem);
                        } else {
                            currentTag = RSSXMLTag.IGNORETAG;
                        }
                    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                        String content = xpp.getText();
                        content = content.trim();
                        Log.d("NEWS_WORLD","Content ="+ content);
                        if (newsItem != null) {
                            switch (currentTag) {
                                case TITLE:
                                    if (content.length() != 0) {
                                        if (newsItem.getTitle() != null) {
                                            newsItem.title += content;
                                        } else {
                                            newsItem.title = content;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case IMAGE:
                                    if (content.length() != 0) {
                                        if (newsItem.image != null) {
                                            newsItem.image += content;
                                        } else {
                                            newsItem.image = content;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case DESCRIPTION:
                                    if (content.length() != 0) {
                                        if (newsItem.description != null) {
                                            newsItem.description += content;
                                        } else {
                                            newsItem.description = content;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case LINK:
                                    if (content.length() != 0) {
                                        if (newsItem.linkUrl != null) {
                                            newsItem.linkUrl += content;
                                        } else {
                                            newsItem.linkUrl = content;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case DATE:
                                    if (content.length() != 0) {
                                        if (newsItem.postDate != null) {
                                            newsItem.postDate += content;
                                        } else {
                                            newsItem.postDate = content;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    eventType = xpp.next();
                }
                Log.v("tst", String.valueOf((newsdata.size())));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).hidePDialog();

                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Request Time out error. Your internet connection is too slow to work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Connection Server error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Network connection error! Check your internet Setting",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if (error instanceof ParseError){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Parsing error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    }

}
*/
```

I am also writing a NewsListAdapter code

```
package com.tandon.mynewsapp.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.tandon.mynewsapp.R;
import com.tandon.mynewsapp.app.AppController;
import com.tandon.mynewsapp.models.News;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Abhishek Tandon on 09-07-2016.
 */
public class NewsListAdapters extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<News> newsdata; // bring news list data with id, title and data
    private Context context; //where to display

    public NewsListAdapters(Context context, List<News> list){
        this.context = context;
        this.newsdata = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return newsdata.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_row, null);
        }
        else{
            view = convertView;
        }

        News news = newsdata.get(position);
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pub_date_time);
        NetworkImageView image = (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgview);

        //Log.d("NEWS_WORLD",news.image);
        image.setImageUrl(news.getImage(), AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader());
        title.setText(news.getTitle());
        description.setText(news.postDate);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you use `Picasso` library to set the image and `Html.fromHtml()` method to set the text?

Comment: There is no need to use any extra library to solve this question. I did not use Picasso library but try to find the exact URL of image from the description fetched by the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it myself and there is no need to download any images to the user's device. Although they are rendering the image by writing binary data to the body. but I can get the image-URL from the string.

```
 public String getImage() {
    if (description.startsWith("<a ")) {            
        String cleanUrl = description.substring(description.indexOf("src=") + 5, description.indexOf("/>") - 2);
        return cleanUrl;
    } else {
        return image;
    }
 }
```

In this code I just find the right URL of image that is between "src=" and a closing tag "/>". And return this clean image to the method.

This Solved my problem. :)

Answer (score -2):

Your image URL have type : http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/photo/507610.cms. You must be replace **.cms** to **.jpeg** before display

Comment: You make sure ```image.getImage()``` match with URL on RSS. If you match you should be [read official](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) to display image from URL. Or replace Volley to Picasso, Glide...

Comment: To solve this I just need to find the exact URL between "src=" and "/>". so I use indesOf in android code and its works. see my answer below of this page.